# Как "прилепить" линию к верху блока

Tags: html, css

Есть такой блок который нужно сверстать:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня получилось так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```css
.active-line {
    border: 5px solid #CBAB3A;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    outline: 0;
}
.hadjj-content-methods-blocks {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 20px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 5px;
    
    width: 280px;
    height: 180px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px !important;
    /* Для явности добавил бордер */
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.hcmb-title {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.hcmb-date {
    color: #828282;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.hcmd-methods {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="hadjj-content-methods-blocks">
<div class="active-line"></div>
<div class="hcmb-title">«Люкс»</div>
<div class="hcmb-date">20 июля - 11 августа</div>
<div class="hcmd-methods">
<div class="hcmbm-kaaba"></div>
<div class="hcmbm-detail">
<div class="hcmbmd-methods">
<div class="plane-method"></div>
</div>
<div class="hcmbmd-price">от 155 000 Р</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Думаю для проблемной части этого кода хватит -->
```

Как видите эта линия в моем исполнении выглядит вообще не так как нужно, не могу понять откуда этот отступ и как его убрать. **Как сделать чтобы эта линия `.active-line` плотно прилегала к верху блока `.hadjj-content-methods-blocks`?**

Comment: так у вас же padding установлены

Comment: @Alpha Разве у меня верхний не стоит paddin не равен 0?

Comment: я думал речь идет о боковых отступах

Comment: @Alpha действительно, боковые тоже были, исправил, спасибо, похоже исправил почему то когда копировал код в вопрос, но верхний еще остается

Comment: Замените justify-content: space-evenly; на justify-content: start;

Comment: @VitaliyAntal пхпхпх, ну и ну, спасибо, оставьте как ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас стоит равномерное распределение по высоте.
Замените

```
justify-content: space-evenly;
```

на

```
justify-content: start
```

Если требуется равномерное распределение. можно использовать

```
justify-content: space-between;
```